# How to add an approval stage in DroneCI pipeline?

Tags: continuous-integration, cicd, drone.io

We would like to create a controlled multi-environment build pipeline in DroneCI but could not find any option to include an approval stage.

Flow:- `Test → Approve(Manual input) → Prod`

Please suggest a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well.

So, Drone doesn't support approval steps as of now. But you may use [Drone API](https://docs.drone.io/api/builds/build_promote/) and [native promotion](https://docs.drone.io/promote/) (for manual promotion.)
Also, for a multi-environment build pipeline you may refer to plugins -

1. https://github.com/microadam/drone-config-changeset-conditional
2. https://github.com/bitsbeats/drone-tree-config 
   *Note these are plugins supported by Drone version 1.3 or above. Also these are 3rd party plugins which are not maintained or supported by Drone.*
   For more on this you can refer to our previous discussions on discourse here -
3. [Is there away to add an approval step on pipelines?](https://discourse.drone.io/t/is-there-away-to-add-an-approval-step-on-pipelines/7984)
4. [Drone.io How to control multi-module build pipeline where modules are interdependent for CI](https://discourse.drone.io/t/drone-io-how-to-control-multi-module-build-pipeline-where-modules-are-interdependent-for-ci/5643).

Thanks for reaching out and feel free to share any further blockers or updates on this.